# Golang: gorm use Find(&model) for non gorm migrate table

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

There is table `customer_account` (`postgres`) which one was migrate from YII2.

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test_table (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('test_table_id_seq'::regclass),
  data JSONB
);
```

In go project i try to get value from this table.

```
type TableGo struct {
    Id int
    Data string `gorm:"type:jsonb"`
}

    table := TableGo{}
    db.Where("id = ?", 75).Find(&table)
    println(table.Data)
```

But there is `(pq: relation "table_gos" does not exist)`

How i can link structure which table without `db.AutoMigrate(&TableGo{})`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think table name in your migration script is wrong. Because it is not in GORM convention. If you want to use that name,you can use following method in your model for custom table name.

```
func (m *Model) TableName() string {
    return "custom_table_name"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
func(TableGo) TableName() string {
    return "account_status"
}
```

Comment: Does this still work, in the latest version of gorm?